# Visual Studio assembly reference version conflicts due to specific version being set to False

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, reference, assemblies, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a solution with many projects. In Visual Studio 2010, clicking properties for an assembly reference displays a newer version when comparing with the actual reference in the csproj file.

Specifically the csproj file has:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

But VS2010 links and displays version 4.0.0.0 obvioussly because of `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>`

Do I have to manually update every singe assembly reference in every project??? by deleting and re-adding the 3.0.0.0 ?

Is there a way to search & replace all the .csproj files in one operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to have your assemblies all reference version 3.0.0.0 again?  If so, then you would just need to set SpecificVersion back to true for all projects that reference the assembly.  This could be done from the references of the project using the properties for the reference.

You could also do this by editing the csproj files in a text editor and remove "False" from the assemblies that you want to reference 3.0.0.0 again as the default value is true.

If you are only looking to do this for a specific assembly, then I expect this to be a manual process as I am not aware of a tool that will help do this.

If you were looking to set specific version to true for all assemblies in all of your projects, then you may be able do a find and replace in the project files replacing "False" with "".